# Add extra attribute in laravel 4.2 confide's login attempt

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am using https://github.com/Zizaco/confide package with laravel 4.2

I don't want to delete user permanently from my db that is why I add deleted_at field in users table.

now i have two row with same username & email id but first row is deleted and 2nd is not. But when I login using confide I got the first row and it's not login.

How to solved this problem ?

Comment: Why do you have two rows with the same username and email to begin with?

Comment: Hi @Jerodev some one signup with username say 'jack' and email is 'jack@gmail.com' , now admin delete this user, I just soft delete it. Again using same username and email I create his account.In that situation I have two row one marked as deleted another is not.